# How to locate the web element via sibling in python?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

[image: attachment]

How to locate "check"in selenium, which corresponds to a button I need to click?

I can not locate it directly. I have to use id='animal'. There is no error if I try below, but there is no response.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id="animal"]//following-sibling::div[contains(@style,"height:10px")]').find_element_by_xpath('//input[@value="check"]')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use XPath

```
//div[@id="animal"]/following-sibling::div/input[@value="check"]
```

or modify your code as

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id="animal"]/following-sibling::div[contains(@style,"height:10px")]').find_element_by_xpath('./input[@value="check"]')
```

Note that I replaced `//input` which means *input node somewhere on the page (returns the first found input in DOM)* with `./input` which means *input node that is child of current node (returns the first found input in target div)*

Comment: Your methods work. It seems `/following-sibling` or  `//following-sibling` does not matter.

Comment: Yes. `/following-sibling` or `//following-sibling` does not really matters in this case

Comment: Why not do a single search? By chaining them you are hitting the page twice.

Comment: @Jeff My solution is to fetch required `input` by single XPath expression. The second (additional) solution is just to explain why OP failed with its initial code

Comment: You are right. I saw the first line but didn't notice that it was a combined locator. I was focused on the second line.